# Plot Vertical Line from custom data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to plot a vertical line using custom date from array.

What I'm trying to code is iterate all values using a for loop, and then plotting a vertical line, with a span of 1 futures day. That's the main target.

The code looks like that:

```
//@version=5

indicator('VertLine_Test', overlay=true)
start_date = array.from("2022-12-26 15:15","2023-01-05 01:45","2023-01-10 16:30") // and so on  

// Iterate array
counter = -1
for i=-1 to array.size(start_date)
    counter := i

counter := counter -1 // assign index Array

string_date = array.get(start_date,counter)  // get the value based on index -> return Ex.2023-01-10 16:30

// Draw VerticalLine
drawVerticalLine(targetTime) =>
    line.new(x1=targetTime, y1=low, x2=targetTime, y2=high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#ea5e50, 10), style=line.style_solid, width=2)

targetTime = timestamp(string_date)  // Assign value and convert to Timestamp
drawVerticalLine(targetTime)   // Call function for draws Vertical Line
```

Now when I run the code, I get an error like this:

```
Compilation error. Cannot call 'timestamp' with argument 'dateString'='string_date'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected
```

I'm struggle with that. What's could be the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `timestamp()` can't take a `series string` as an argument, but needs a `constant string` (a `string` that can't be changed during execution).

You can fix this by making an array of `timestamp` instead of array of strings.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

start_date = array.from(timestamp("2022-12-26 15:15"),timestamp("2023-01-05 01:45"),timestamp("2023-01-10 16:30")) // and so on  

for date in start_date
    line.new(x1=date, y1=low, x2=date, y2=high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#ea5e50, 10), style=line.style_solid, width=2)
```

Comment: Thank you Mr_Statler. It work perfectly. Now i understood where was the trouble 